# Cannot instantiate the type GeometricObject

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, abstract

GeometricObject is an abstract class, when i try to run the test code (shown bellow) i get the the error "Cannot instantiate the type GeometricObject"
Any ideas how to fix it ?

```
  import geometricobject.GeometricObject;
    public class TestGeometricObject {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        GeometricObject obj1 = new GeometricObject();
        GeometricObject obj2 = new GeometricObject("blue", true);
        System.out.println("Object 1: " + obj1.toString());
        System.out.println("Object 2: " + obj2.toString());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because it's an abstract class. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated. Read more about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).

You need to `extend` it in some concrete class, and then you can instantiate.

Comment: I already read that doc, i'm asking if there's a way around it.

Comment: Only `extend`ing, as in the answer

Comment: So i need to extend GeometricObject to another non asbtract class and instantiate it from there ?

Comment: Or change the class, so it isn’t `abstract` anymore.

Comment: iHate2 if you find this helpful, close the issue by marking answer as correct

Comment: I need it as an abstract class for the project.

Comment: Then do as I wrote... Extend it and instantiate as an abstract class: `GeometricObject geometricObject = new GeometricObjectImpl();` where `GeometricObjectImpl` extends `GeometricObject`

Comment: always glad to help:)